# using series as lenght of ta.percentrank

Tags: pine-script

I need to use ta.percentrank with the maximum the possible lenght for new listings.

I try to use bar_index for it but problem is bar_index is series and lenght should be simple int. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In npinescript (version 5) it is impossible to change a variable type from series int to simple int.
You have to find a workaround.